# dokku asking for password

Tags: git, ssh, dokku

I have setup a digital ocean box with dokku on my home computer. I've added ssh keys for both my home and work computer. I've then turned password access off. Accessing the server from both computers works via ssh without the need for a password. Git push with dokku@ however will only work from my home computer. What am I missing? - should I just create a new droplet and try again?.

Comment: Did you declare your new key in the dokku instance as mentioned in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/dokku-add-new-ssh-key?

Comment: Well `root@url` isn't the same than `dokku@url`. Do you have only one set of ssh key in your `~/.ssh`? (`id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`?)

Comment: That makes sense, I'm not able to check it yet but I'm guessing thats probably it.

Comment: Ok. I have added an answer, that I will expend depending on your feedback after your test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check on your work computer:

- if the `~/.ssh/id_rsa`(`.pub`) is the [right key added to dokku](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/dokku-add-new-ssh-key)
- if the url uses the right user: `root@url` isn't the same than `dokku@url`

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar error. I needed to run this command:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh progriumapp.com "sudo sshcommand acl-add dokku progrium"
```

This adds an ssh key for the user. Make sure that your first `$ source ~/.bashrc` on the server to make sure the command runs as expected.

Comment: In my case I needed to ssh to `root@progriumapp.com`. Updated example: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@progriumapp.com "sudo sshcommand acl-add dokku [description]"` `[description]` can be anything to describe the public key (i.e. home, work, ..). One word max.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can add sshs simple: dokku ssh-keys:add dokku ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub